# Adobe Illustrator, Save to Swatches Panel with RGB Hex names instead of RGB 0-255 Values

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a setting in Adobe Illustrator that would make all saved swatches from the Color Guide save as RGB Hex instead of RGB 0-255 values?

I'm not even sure if this is possible...

It would save a lot of time, allowing me to just double-click the name of each swatch, then copy the hex value, and paste into whatever .css file I'm editing...rather than having to double click the color, click inside the hex box, and copy that way.  For one-off's, thats no big deal, but when dealing with tons of colors, every click adds up time-wise.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[Screenshot, showing specifically what I'd like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccjU2.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*
 Run this script to rename swatch rgb color to  corresponding hex value 
 For example, 'R=108 G=125 B=87' will be '#6c7d57'
 Note: script works with RGB color only.
 Befor run script select swatch colors in illustrator's Swathes Panel.
 */

var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
var selSwatches = myDoc.swatches.getSelected();

for (var i=0; i<selSwatches.length; i++)
{
    swcolor = selSwatches[i].color;
    if (swcolor.typename=='RGBColor')
   {
       selSwatches[i].name = rgbToHex(swcolor.red, swcolor.green, swcolor.blue) ;
   }
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) 
{
        var hex = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
        {
            var n = typeof arguments[i] == 'number' ? arguments[i] : parseInt(arguments[i]);
            if (isNaN(n) || n < 0 || n > 255) 
            {
                return null;
            }
         hex += (n < 16 ? '0' : '') + n.toString(16);
        }
        return hex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!
I tried to upvote your post, but it won't let me.